# How to limit a max number for a NUMBER input in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am now trying to create a new input which will reject if the number user type in exceed the limit but it is not working the

let say the max number is `99`
Currently my best way is to create something like this

```
<input
    type="text"
    :maxlength="2"
    aria-controls="none"
    class="number-field-input"
    inputmode="numeric"
    pattern="/d+"
    v-model="inputOne"
  />
```

This will limit the max number to `99` since the `max length is 2` but I don't want something like this I want something like this but its not working

```
<input
        type="number"
        min="1"
        max="99" //may not be 99 but something between 1 and 99
        aria-controls="none"
        class="number-field-input"
        inputmode="numeric"
        pattern="/d+"
        v-model="inputOne"
   />
```

Comment: not working how? *may not be 99 but something between 1 and 99*, then set min=2, max=98

Comment: For example the max number `150` when user type in `201` I want the number to automatically convert to 150. Right now even user type in 1000 it still passing

Comment: yeah thats normal, add a watcher, watch: {inputOne(v){if(v<1) v = 1; if(v>99) v = 99; }}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use watcher :

```js
const { ref, watch } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    let inputOne = ref(0)
    watch(inputOne,
      (newValue) => {
        inputOne.value = newValue > 99 ? 99 : newValue
      },
    );
    return { inputOne };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
<div>
  <input
    type="number"
    min="1"
    max="99" 
    aria-controls="none"
    class="number-field-input"
    inputmode="numeric"
    pattern="/d+"
    v-model="inputOne"
   />
</div>
```

Comment: need to include `-9999`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve that by single line of code with the help of `@input` event.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: 0
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="value" @input="() => { if(value > 150 || value < 0) { value = 150 }}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

const min = ref(50)
const max = ref(50)
const maxError = ref(false)

const validateMin = () => {
  maxError.value = false
  if (min.value < 50) {
    min.value = 50
  } else if (min.value > 20000) {
    min.value = 20000
  } else if (min.value > max.value) {
    maxError.value = true
  }
}
const validateMax = () => {
  maxError.value = false
  if (max.value < 50) {
    max.value = 50
  } else if (max.value > 20000) {
    max.value = 20000
  } else if (max.value < min.value) {
    maxError.value = true
  }
}
```

Html Code:

```
                  <label for="min">En Az</label>
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    name="min"
                    id="min"
                    v-model="min"
                    @blur="validateMin()"
                    placeholder="En az"
                  />
         
                  <label for="max">En Çok</label>
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    name="max"
                    id="max"
                    v-model="max"
                    @blur="validateMax()"
                    placeholder="En fazla"
                  />
              

                <small v-if="maxError" class="col-span-2 text-red-600"
                  >Max değeri Min değerinden küçük olamaz!</small>
```